# Argument of type 'typeof LogoAvatar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<LogoProps & Partial<WithTheme>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why argument of type `typeof LogoAvatar` is not assignable to parameter of type `ComponentType<LogoProps & Partial<WithTheme>`

Code:

```
import * as React from "react";

import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";

const styles = {
 avatar: {
  margin: 10
  }
 };

interface LogoProps {
  lender: string;
  src: string;
 }

class LogoAvatar extends React.Component<LogoProps> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    let l = this.props.lender;
    let s = this.props.src;

if (l === "Seacoast") {
  s =
    "https://www.seacoastbank.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Seacoast-Dark-Logo-compressor.png?t=1532980735522&width=472&name=Seacoast-Dark-Logo-compressor.png";
}

if (l === "nbkc") {
  s = "http://measuremedia.com/img/nbkclogo.jpg";
}

return <Avatar src={s} className="avatar" />;
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(LogoAvatar);
```

Error Message:

```
Argument of type 'typeof LogoAvatar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<LogoProps & Partial<WithTheme> & { classes: Record<"row" | "avatar", string>; }>'.
  Type 'typeof LogoAvatar' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<LogoProps & Partial<WithTheme> & { classes: Record<"row" | "avatar", string>; }>'.
    Type 'typeof LogoAvatar' provides no match for the signature '(props: LogoProps & Partial<WithTheme> & { classes: Record<"row" | "avatar", string>; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check withStyles limitations in Typescript

https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#decorating-components

Because of TS limitations you should use the function approach instead of this one.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles for me:

```
import * as React from "react";

import { withStyles, WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";

const styles = {
 avatar: {
  margin: 10
  }
 };

interface LogoProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  lender: string;
  src: string;
 }

class LogoAvatar extends React.Component<LogoProps> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    let l = this.props.lender;
    let s = this.props.src;

if (l === "Seacoast") {
  s =
    "https://www.seacoastbank.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Seacoast-Dark-Logo-compressor.png?t=1532980735522&width=472&name=Seacoast-Dark-Logo-compressor.png";
}

if (l === "nbkc") {
  s = "http://measuremedia.com/img/nbkclogo.jpg";
}

return <Avatar src={s} className="avatar" />;
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(LogoAvatar);
```

See if it runs.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks so much! This was my first go at Typescript so I'm still getting the hang of it :)